# Function to call either single post or category

Tags: php, functions

I'm trying to display content depending on if a user is in a category or a single post.

The function i'm using if this is a category is:

```
<?php if (is_category('')) { ?>
```

Similarly the function i'm using if this is a single post is:

```
<?php } elseif (is_single($post)) { ?>
```

How can I join these 2 functions creating a single function call to say if this is any category OR any single post?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the same if/else, you can just combine into `if ( is_category() || is_single() )`. You don't need to pass anything to is_category() or is_single() most of the time, unless you are looking for a category or post in particular.

Comment: Exactly right. `if ( is_category() || is_single() )` will return true if the current page is a **Category Archive Index** *or* a **Single Blog Post**.